# How does subscribe (unsubscribe) work internally in the redux store?

Tags: javascript, redux

in [this guide by Dan Abramov](https://egghead.io/lessons/react-redux-implementing-store-from-scratch) he recreates a basic implementation of the redux store.

The `subscribe` method looks like this

```
const subscribe = (listener)=>{
    listeners.push(listener) //subscribe
      return ()=>{
        listeners = listeners.filter(l => l !== listener) //unsubscribe
      }
  }
```

every time `dispatch` is called it calls all the functions in the `listeners` array.

from the redux docs:

> To unsubscribe the change listener, invoke the function returned by subscribe.
>
> `const unsubscribe = store.subscribe(handleChange)`

Why is it handled that way? The function seems very counterintuitive to me and looks more complicated than implementing a dedicated `unsubscribe` method.

Comment: I think it's more a syntactic sugar!